# how to prepend an icon to error messages on form validation jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, jquery-validate

I used the following code to prepend an icon to the form validation error messages but when the user clicks on the form field and clicks away without fixing the field the icon disappears:

```
errorPlacement: 
    function(label, element) {
        label.prepend('<i class="fa-solid fa-triangle-exclamation fa-lg" style="color: #c0392b;"></i> ');
        label.insertAfter(element);
    },
```

what do I need to do to keep the icon on the error message?

Comment: The `errorPlacement()`  function isn't standard so post some HTML and more JS as a [mcve].

Comment: @zer00ne, while I agree the OP should post more code, the `errorPlacement` function is a very standard option.

Comment: Based on the code posted above, I see no reason for the icon to have disappeared when clicking away from a field unless the validation error was fixed.  Please post enough code to reproduce the issue.

Comment: @Sparky at the time of my comment there was no `jquery-validate` tag.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the issue by using just CSS:

```
    label.error::before{
        font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
        content: "\f071 ";
        display: inline-block;
        padding-right: 5px;
        vertical-align: middle;
        font-weight: 900;
    }
```

This added an icon to the error message and the icon stays if the user click outside of the field without fixing it.